# Basic doubts related to rendering of texture region in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I have just recently started using libgdx.I have some doubts regarding rendering of texture region.Here is my code

```
@Override
public void create() {      
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, h/w);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/libgdx.png"));
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 512, 275);

    sprite = new Sprite(region);
    sprite.setSize(1f, 1f * sprite.getHeight() / sprite.getWidth());
    sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth()/2, sprite.getHeight()/2);
    sprite.setPosition(-sprite.getWidth()/2, -sprite.getHeight()/2);
    sprite.setRotation(30);
}
```

In this case sprite renders perfectly.
But if i change line

```
sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth()/2, sprite.getHeight()/2);
```

to

```
sprite.setOrigin(any constant values like 50, sprite.getHeight()/2);
```

i only get blue screen.
same thing happens when i set position this way.

Also if i use something like

```
sprite.setOrigin(0.53*sprite.getWidth()/2, sprite.getHeight()/2);
```

it renders as expected, why does it renders as expected when i use any multiple of sprite.getWidth() and not when i use constant of same value.

**EDIT:**

Here are my resize and render methods

```
@Override
public void render() {      
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}
```

I have not changed anything here.

Comment: Can you show your resize and render methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might depend on your rendering camera setting. It cuold be caused by setting the origin out of bounds. In other words, try setting it to (for example) much lower or much higher values.

Comment: It did not work, i tried setting camera to 0,0 and then to 200,200

Comment: I see no point in setting the camera to 0, 0. I meant experimenting with setting the origin. Try to print out sprite.getWidth()/2 and you get the value, that you should be experimenting with.

Comment: My doubt is why are constnats not working, for example my sprite has width of 512 pixels, setting origin using sprite.getWidth()/2 or using 256 should produce same result but it does not.Why is it happening?

Comment: Put `System.out.println(sprite.getWidth()/2);` after setting the origin, I am quite sure, it will give you some suprising value.

Comment: Yes, that really surprised me its 0.5, but why did it happen, should not it be 256.

Comment: Because it's the width of the sprite, not the texture. And when dealing with sprite's origin, you should use values in terms of width of the sprite.

Comment: Now i got it sprite.setSize(1f, 1f * sprite.getHeight() / sprite.getWidth()); sets width to one, thanx bro.